# Cannot locate Gemfile or .bundle/ directory

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

When I run `bundle install` I'm getting this error `Cannot locate Gemfile or .bundle/ directory`. Ruby version 2.2.3 and rails version 4.2.5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you're in the root directory of the app and then run `bundle`